# Splitting semicolon-separated vector into respective columns

Tags: r

I have a data set with two variables that appear in a single column and separated by ';' as follows:

```
Date;Stock Price
0   01.09.2017;8941.62
1   04.09.2017;8864.46
2   05.09.2017;8869.56
3   06.09.2017;8859.47
4   07.09.2017;8906.6
```

How to separate the data have 2 separate columns namely: date and stock price using R?

Comment: The separate command should work for this in dplyr. `dplyr::separate(df, "Date;Stock Price", c("Date", "Stock_Price"), sep = ";")`.

Comment: if you read this dataset from a falie, you can also use something like: read.csv('your file', sep = ';'). The same should work with read.table, etc

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have managed to do it. I'm grateful.

Comment: Is this in a file?  In an R object?  If the latter please show `dput(head(X))` where X is the R object.  See the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag.